# Looking for a strong Phd Topic in Predictive Analytics in the context of Big Data

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, data-mining, statistics, predictive-modeling

I'm going to start a Computer Science phd this year and for that I need a research topic. I am interested in Predictive Analytics in the context of Big Data. I am interested by the area of Education (MOOCs, Online courses...). In that field, what are the unexplored areas that can help me choose a strong topic? Thanks.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please try to narrow it down. What are you interested in?

Comment: Hello Sean, thanks for your answer. I have just edited my question and narrow it down a bit. I specified that I am interested in the area of Education with the new revoluions like MOOCs as an example...

Comment: One of the most promising tools for machine learning with big data is [MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html) from Apache Spark project. There's already a number of methods implemented, but much more is to be written yet. If you are also interested in education, take some algorithmic problem from it (e.g. predicting student's score or course efficiency) and design solution for that problem. Having told that, I should warn you that for using big data solutions your data should really be pretty large, and I'm not sure MOOCs will give that much data.

Comment: I would like to thank you first for your detailed answer. Yes you are right, the availability of the so much large data is very crucial. I will try to think about that and get back to you :) Thanks for your proposition of the subject :)

Comment: Our start up is looking for academics to work on big data via stock analysis, if that field interests you, feel free to reach out.

Comment: Oh, and I know that Universities are very interested in retention rates of students, so creating a model to predict retention rates based on the classes taken might be one proposal you could make to your university...

Comment: Hello @EmilyCrutcher. I apologize for the delay, it has been ages since I didn't check this post. I am very excited to start working with you in this project !

Comment: teaches me not to check my stackoverflow email :-).  If you are still interested my direct email emily at equitieslab dot com

Comment: can you suggest me any topic for master's thesis in predictive analytics in the context of big data.

Comment: what is big data and data sciences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a fellow CS Ph.D. defending my dissertation in a Big Data-esque topic this year (I started in 2012), the best piece of material I can give you is in a [link](http://www.rpajournal.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/A3.pdf).

This is an article written by two Ph.D.s from MIT who have talked about Big Data and MOOCs. Probably, you will find this a good starting point. BTW, along this note, if you really want to come up with a valid topic (that a committee and your adviser will let you propose, research and defend) you need to read LOTS and LOTS of papers. The majority of Ph.D. students make the fatal error of thinking that some 'idea' they have is new, when it's not and has already been done. You'll have to do something truly original to earn your Ph.D. Rather than actually focus on forming an idea right now, you should do a good literature survey and the ideas will 'suggest themselves'. Good luck! It's an exciting time for you.

Comment: Thanks M.Dax a lot ! Yes you are right, thank you very much for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

- Limitations of ML-Powered Predictive Models
- Predictive Models on Conversion Studies for the Level Premium Term Plans
- Data Management
- Business intelligence(BI) predictive Analytics
- Big data and Market Intelligence
- Educational data mining
- Automation of predictive models
- predictive data quality using ML
- Open source Data Mining
- Data Mining System
- Data mining Trends
- Health data mining
- Web Analytics solution
- Data Mining marketing
- Data Mining in Search Engine Analytics
- Fraud & Security
- Risk Management